# Numbers dont change

Tags: c#, recursion

For example, when  I enter number=3  and times=3. It outputs numbers like
9
9
9
but it should be like 3 6 9
Here is my code, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many times you want to multiply it");
        int times = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Multiply(number, times));
        }
    }

    public static int Multiply(int number, int times)
    {
        if (times != 0)
        {
            return number + Multiply(number, times - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great chance to learn how to use the debugger (since it's such a simple/small program and you can see the error easily). Put breakpoints just before the loop and at the start of `Multiply`. Step and look at the values of your variables

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `times` rather than `i` to `Multiply` in your loop.